# Reactjs hooks to run function in parent from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parant that contains a child and a function within the parent that I wish to run form the child. However with the current code what is happening is the function is ran instantly instead of when the button is pressed on the child component. any ideas? Here is the code:

```
const Parent  = () => {

const [showPayment, setShowPayment] = useState(true);
const [showSignupComplete, setShowSignupComplete] = useState(false);

const CompleteSignup = () => {
  setShowPayment(false);
  setShowSignupComplete(true);
}
 
return (
<div>
{showPayment ?(
      <Payment paymentChange={CompleteSignup}/>
):null }

{showSignupComplete ?( 
  <div> Sign up complete </div>
):null }
</div>
}

const Payment = ({paymentChange}) => { 
  const handleSubmitSub = async (event) => {
  paymentChange
  }

return (
 <div>
 <Button
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className="submit"
           onClick={handleSubmitSub}
           >
            Complete Payment
          </Button>
       </div>
)
```

}

I've updated the code with the suggestions below. however get the error: paymentChange is not a function

Comment: You are calling that function instead of passing that function reference. `<Payment paymentChange={CompleteSignup}/>`.

Comment: I've tried that however that does not work at all

Comment: inside handleSubmitSub  change paymentChange => paymentChange() and Payment = (paymentChange) to Payment = ({ paymentChange }), I suggest you to read the [new React}(https://beta.reactjs.org/learn) docs

Comment: Component receives props as object. In payment component, do this: `const Payment = ({ paymentChange }) => {...` and in handleSubmitSub function, call paymentChange function just like @Azzy said

Comment: I did both of the things suggested and get this error: 
paymentChange is not a function at handleSubmitSub

Comment: @Robert Please create a sandbox so someone help to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reformatted your code for better readability
It actually works. `completeSignup` is called in `Payment` and it changes states in `Parent`

The only thing I fixed is `handleSubmitSub` in `Payment` component

In `handleSubmitSub` you should call `paymentChange` as a function()
Like this

`const handleSubmitSub = async (event) => {paymentChange()}`

Full code:

```
const Parent  = () => {
  const [showPayment, setShowPayment] = useState(true);
  const [showSignupComplete, setShowSignupComplete] = useState(false);

  const completeSignup = () => {
      setShowPayment(false);
      setShowSignupComplete(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {showPayment && <Payment paymentChange={completeSignup}/>}
      {
        showSignupComplete && 
        <div> Sign up complete </div>
      }
    </div>
  )   
}

const Payment = ({paymentChange}) => { 
  const handleSubmitSub = async (event) => {paymentChange()}

  return (
    <div>
      <button
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className="submit"
           onClick={handleSubmitSub}
           >
            Complete Payment
        </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

P.S: I'd recommend naming functions inside components with a lower camelCase = () => {}, so those functions will not be misread as a react Component = () => {}

Comment: You're correct and thank you as in this actually works. I realized my problem wasn't how I was doing it but rather I was sending other values actually before the function so i had  "const Payment = (values, paymentChange) => {" and in order to pull the function when I did it like this I had to then use "values.paymentChange()" and it worked. However your answer is correct for what I posted code wise and I'll mark it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your naming is a bit confucing here, that onClick you put on the  component is not an actual event handler, it's a prop. You have to accept the "handleSubmitSub" function in the child component as props.

In the child component do the following:

```
const Button = ({onClick as fn}) => {

/// your code here.....

return (
<button onClick={fn}>YOUR BUTTON TEXT</button>
)

}
```

Comment: I can't do it that way because I have other data that I will be passing to the child and the button command needs to execute a function first bc of this which then contains the function from the parent. I just simplified the code for the example.

Comment: Really sorry to say that, but I can't provide a better solution for your problem if I'm working with a code that doesn't reflect your needs correctly.